# Worst-case exponential runtime for some special terms

Tags: prolog

This question is based on [a relatively recent issue on the Scryer Prolog GitHub page](https://github.com/mthom/scryer-prolog/issues/1389).

Consider the following predicate:

```
ptree(1).
ptree(X+X) :-
   ptree(X).
```

Using `ptree/1` we can easily get exponentially-sized trees which can be represented in linear space.

`ground/1` and `(is)/2` can run in exponential time or in linear time—depending on the implementation of the Prolog system.

Here's my actual question:

> Which commonly used builtin and library predicates are (potentially) affected by this issue?

So far I found [`term_variables/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#term_variables) and [`library(terms)`](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/4.0.0/html/sicstus/lib_002dterms.html).

*But are there more?*

Comment: If only there would be a way to read the code.... ah I guess we'll never know

Comment: @TA_intern. What code are you talking about?

Comment: In some circles they call it "source code". I prefer to call it "codes", as in, "please give codes".

Comment: @TA_intern. Yes, it's all in the code:)  But not in a reasonably explicit way.  Also my question was not only about Scryer Prolog, but also about other systems which may or may not be open source...

Comment: There is a related property. I never had the time to re-evaluate that recently but as far as I can remember, SICStus remembers identities after unification (and it could be even `==`) whereas SWI, Scryer (to say the least) doesn't.

Comment: ... or in other words, both SWI and Scryer build some extra temporary infrastructure to handle identical subterms (and thereby also infinite rational trees) and discard this upon success of the unification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other examples using [blam](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/yap-prolog/blam.pl):

On GNU Prolog and Trealla Prolog, `(=)/2` and `(==)/2` exhibit the same issue with `bleq/1` and `bleqeq/1` respectively.

On GNU Prolog, Trealla Prolog, Scryer Prolog, [`acyclic_term/1`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#acyclic_term) is affected.

---

As long as a property needs to hold recursively like `acyclic_term/1`, `(=)/2` or a result is built recursively like `term_variables/2`, this issue can happen.

Memoization is the way to solve this. Looking at Scryer (`$ git grep "let.*tabu"`), it's using memoization for `(=)/2` and `compare/3`.

But memoization wouldn't work on:

```
blem([]).
blem([L|R]) :-
    blem(R),
    same_length(R, L),
    blem(L).
```

[Term sharing](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1311.pdf) is the next step to not miss the memoization technique.

Comment: One relatively recent [attempt](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.1311.pdf) to solve this.

Comment: Interesting paper.

Comment: Memoization in the context of Prolog typically means to remember an instance of some predicae. But what you refer to as memorization is rather remembering an address.